# Looping through channels, outputting field name, field type, field value

Tags: channel-entries, channel

Given any Channel, is it possible to loop through all the entries and output the following:

- field name
- field type
- field value

Assume that the Channel is unknown and can be any Channel. This means that I don't know ahead of time what fields there are in the Channel.

For the field values, I assume that I would need extra logic to display its corresponding values (e.g. a grid might need to have a nested loop, etc.).

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst not available for front end, this is a must for all installs: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-variables

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick answer but exp:query could handle most of this - certainly listing channel fields and types would be easy...I do something similar to help build stash models for channels, like this:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT field_name FROM exp_channel_fields WHERE group_id = '47' "}
       {exp:stash:set name="{field_name}"}{{field_name}}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:query}
```

exp_channel_fields has the type as well.

The content will be harder, I'd look to one of the APIs lie RSANs DEEP or maybe OpenAPI to do that maybe?

Comment: I thought I recall seeing something in the EE documentation that showed some code looping -- and doing field type checks, then outputting values. I thought it was `exp:channel:entries`, but I guess not. I doubt it was `exp:query`, though. Does that ring a bell at all?

Comment: Obviously with entries you can can output the field types and values if you know the names, but without the names...of course you can get the names using the above and stash them, for example.  Sorry, my answer is not complete but I'm a bit bust, jsut trying to get you started..